# Windows Phone 8 Pesapal integration with WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

My app fetchers selling digital goods and I don't want to use in-app purchases for this purpose instead I would like to
use **pesapal** integration with the help of a `WebBrowser control`. I have checked the [store policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx#pol_10_8) regarding this as well as the
[`WebBrowser control` security best practices for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff462081(v=vs.105).aspx) but now confused since I am not still sure if it is legal and will my app be
rejected if I integrate payment using a `WebBrowser control`. ? Any help is appriciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, we know you want to sell digital goods in your app. According to [the Windows Store Policies 10.8 Financial Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx#pol_10_8), we can know that **you could need to use the Microsoft in-app purchase API to sell digital items or services that are consumed or used within your app**.

You could need to use a secure third party purchase API for purchase of physical goods or services, real world gambling or charitable contributions.

**Please note** only the tester can pass/fail an app.

Comment: Does this means that I am able to use the in- app `web Browser control` for payments  If the testers are able to test the security of the payment. ???

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a Web controller to load payments, we did this for Ticketsasa.com Application and it was approved before we changed to the current one which uses a different approach. The requirement however is that you must inform the user prior to loading the Web controller that by clicking of a button (or the event that loads the web Controller) will lead them to be redirected to a webpage where they will pay.